# problem with changing the frames in an video with opencv

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ffmpeg

I have a code that runs in the last few months without any problem. The code shows an image from a video with extra data from the relevant db. using the keyboard you can jump around some frames and get better insights. However, in the last week changing the frame of the video stopped working.

I built a small script that show the problem.

```
import cv2

vid_cap_reader_path = "vid_230830_122746_C.avi"
cap_rgb = cv2.VideoCapture(vid_cap_reader_path)

k = 0
while 1:
    if k == ord("q"):
        break
    if k == ord("b"):
        before = cap_rgb.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
        cap_rgb.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, before + 30.0)
        after = cap_rgb.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
        print(f"before = {before} after = {after}")
    ret, img = cap_rgb.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("bla", img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        break
```

This is what is printed to the terminal:

```
[mpeg4 @ 0x1d87400] warning: first frame is no keyframe
before = 36.0 after = 0.0
before = 67.0 after = 0.0
[mpeg4 @ 0x1d87400] warning: first frame is no keyframe
before = 40.0 after = 0.0
[mpeg4 @ 0x1d87400] warning: first frame is no keyframe
```

The video itself doesn't "jump" for the next frame as expected and also most of the properties that opencv have return 0. I tested also `CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`, and `CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` without any lack, although the msec flag did give non-zero results which make no sense.

It is also important to mention that I am building this application in a docker file and I am not using a specific version for my requirements. The tests here are with `opencv-python==4.7.0.68`. Also, the videos are working fine while playing them on VLC.

I was looking around the net for a similar problem from the recent time and didn't find much except this [github issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/23472) that may be similar. I started to downgrade opencv one by one without any luck.

Maybe someone here can help with this issue, or give me a lead to doing something different.

Comment: are you saying that you updated any of the libraries you're using? which one? why is your video file broken?

Comment: the video files aren't seem broken, they work in VLC and other media apps. I cant conform that the libraries where updated however it is possible on my ci/cd process which build the docker image. As mentioned the requirement file was set to use the latest opencv library available.

Answer (score 1):

**Tested the code on Python 3.8.10 using Opencv 4.5.4**

Got this output running the original code on an mp4 file:

**Output**

```python
before = 1.0 after = 31.0
before = 32.0 after = 62.0
before = 63.0 after = 93.0
before = 94.0 after = 124.0
before = 125.0 after = 155.0
before = 156.0 after = 181.0
```

**I was able to go frame by frame as well by changing:**

```python
cap_rgb.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, before + 30.0)
```

to

```python
cap_rgb.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, before)
```

**Output:**

```python
before = 1.0 after = 1.0
before = 2.0 after = 2.0
before = 3.0 after = 3.0
before = 4.0 after = 4.0
before = 5.0 after = 5.0
etc..
```

**A way you might be able to get around the error would be:**

```python
before = cap_rgb.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
if before==0:
    before+=1
else:
   cap_rgb.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, start_frame)
```

**Otherwise it looks like it could just be an issue with your Opencv version.**